# efficient way of calling a 3rd party web service

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services

I currently using [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) for retrieving information for in a mobile application(iOS and Android).

Now my problem is how to design my application so that my application code remains immune to any changes in URL structure from google or any 3rd party service.

Currently Google requires us to use a URL structure like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/output?parameters
```

Now suppose if I have embedded this URL into my code and Google changes this URL or I decide to use some other service, then it would need to modify my code again once it is in production.

Is it possible to do this in some other way, so that my application code can remain immune to any such changes.

I am also streaming and loading some stuff into my application via my own server via PHP. 
So would it be a good idea to send the request for information first to my server, then fetch those details from google's server and return them back to my code in the form required by it.

**Diagrammatically Explaining**

Earlier I was doing this

*My Application -> Request to Google's Server -> Response from Google's Server-> To My app*

Now, I am thinking of this structure

*My Application-> Request to my server with required parameters -> Request to Google's server or whatever 3rd party places API I want to use -> Response to my server -> to my app in required form.*

I know that this approach will add delays to the response but it would let the control in my hands. And also, I could use the same server side script on multiple platforms.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: The title of the question is a bit of a misnomer, since you admit you're willing to sacrifice performance/efficiency for fault-tolerance.

Comment: I know that my approach will be less efficient. But I don't know if that's the only way or is there any other way to achieve the task without sacrificing much of efficiency. Moreover, I am not aware if the delay would be very significant

Comment: You can route everything through your server and if you're looking at a relatively low frequency of requests, I imagine you'll be fine. But if you've got 50+ concurrent requests with a high saturation level (the service makes many requests frequently), I think you might find yourself burned. What you want is a simpler way to update a centrally located service URL which is sent to the client as well. You could do that with a simple config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about implementing your solution but with a one-time call when the application loads?  In other words you would have some kind of registration/login communication when the application starts and download the string/protocol for those requests.  This way you can still have fairly good performance once you establish what format you are using for the requests.

Comment: It would work if I want to control the URL. But what if the format of returning JSON also changes or I use another service which would return entirely different JSON format.

Comment: so just pile in all of those details on one initial call from the app, you are still reducing major overhead by not calling everything through the server.  Whatever you could parse/convert server side could be converted app side and save you some network time.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation accessing 3rd party data, where the access might possibly change in the future but not too much and not too often. The easiest way I found is to put the URL or whatever other data in a config array, which is in my case loaded into `Config` object.
Then I have a class `Importer` that uses `Config` to decide how to get the data. The rest of my app only talks to `Importer`. 
So if the URL ever changes, all I need to do is to change it in my config array.

[Here is more detailed description of the Architecture I am using.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882474/designing-robust-and-testable-architecture-for-importing-large-text-data-from-3r)